# jQuery ajax and php iframe. Form target issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, iframe

overflowers here is the daily question. =)

**Use case & problem description:**

1. I'm submitting a form via jQuery $.ajax({...})

   - The ajax post call trigger an SQL insert done by php.
   - The SQL query is executed successfully and can be checked on the DB.
2. The **iframe** which is used to display the result **didn't get update**.

   - original button attached to form used target="id_of_iframe"*
3. The post destination is in the same url, same target (my_iframe)

So,

- How do I update the iframe with the result data of the $.ajax post?
- Should I add some other controls?
- Some other form submission method with editable post data compliant with iframe?

Thanks to all in advance, have a nice coding-day :)

**The code:**

HTML

```
<html>
  <head>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--the iframe -->
    <iframe src ="iframe.php" 
      class="my_iframe" id="my_iframe" 
      name="my_iframe" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true">
    </iframe>
    <!--the form -->
    <form id="my_form" action="iframe.php" 
     method="post" target="my_iframe">
       <!-- some input fields -->
       <button onclick="my_function"></button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT - JQUERY

```
function my_function(){
   var my_data = .../*go collect form data*/
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "iframe.php",
     data: my_data,
     success:function(response){
         $("#my_frame").html(response);
     }
   });
}
```

**Partial Result:**

1. The chrome console log this warning about jquery.min.js:4

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of
>   its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help,
>   check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

2. Some CSS get buggy and some font/font-weight change

**PS**
In the ajax.success function I've tried this alternative but the issue is the same:

```
$('#my_iframe').append(result);
```

Comment: iframe's body doesn't need to be updated with `html` or `append`.

Comment: are you trying to reload the iframe after the ajax call?

Comment: @mubasharabbas dear mubashar, how should I? :)

Comment: please see the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To update the iframe you can just update it's `src` attribute like so:

```
$('iframe#my_iframe').attr('src', 'iframe.php');
```

put this in your ajax `success` callback. and the iframe will reload.

Comment: Still no work.
The post always get submitted and the success event triggered.